# CSS and JS files only loading on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm experiencing a weird bug in which my CSS and JS files are only loading on Chrome. I've tried different encodes but nothing seems to be working.

Safari seems to load some CSS, with elements appearing in the right order and animating. Yet on firefox no externals are loaded at all.

Could anyone shed some light on this? Thanks

http://keiranlovett.com

URGH: So in a server update somehow the backup decided to ignore a few dozen crucial folders (NOT GOOD) but Chrome wasn't updating the content. There was an encoding error but I was also linking to a dozen missing files while it said I wasn't.

Comment: Possibly a lang and encoding/char set issue.

Comment: Your HTTP server is violating HTTP.  Run Fiddler and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox is reading your CSS as UTF16.

Looking further, it looks like your HTTP server is doing something very wrong.